# Cannot select polygon using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, select

I've created a polygon from lines in a couple of cases where I'm unable to select the polygon using the standard Select Features button. I am able to select the feature using the Attributes Table, but in neither case am I able to actually cut and paste the polygon from that layer to another layer.

Any ideas?

(Using QGIS 2.18 on OSX)

Comment: I've put the shapefiles for the layer at hand and the unselectable polygon here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12PXCpK_EXRMae9e4hOF9bhvasGKCd3lb?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your polygon isn't closed. If you open the Log Messages Panel you'll see a message on the GEOS tab:

```
Exception: IllegalArgumentException: Points of LinearRing do not form a closed linestring
```

Comment: Aha - I'll dig around to see if I can find that - thanks so much! I was guessing / hoping it was something straightforward. Not sure how it's not closed, as all end points are snapped, but I'm sure there's something I've missed. Thanks!